# how do I install older versions of Adobe Flash on Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, flash, chromium

I've found this: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

But is it the correct file to install a flash plugin for chrome? I preferably want to try v11 or 12

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without downgrading Chrome itself. [Chrome bundles a special version of Flash Player targeting the Pepper API.](https://blog.chromium.org/2010/03/bringing-improved-support-for-adobe.html) Any other version you install for other browsers is irrelevant.